# What would cause an Angular2 service to create multiple instances?

Tags: angular

I have created a service and provided it in 'root' in my project (using the standard shortcut). However, it appears to be creating multiple instances instead of using the same instance. I diagnosed this by setting an instance variable ID equal to a random value in the constructor and then printing this to console on method calls.

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
  })

console.log(`Hodor ${this.ID}`);
```

This is a problem since the additional instance doesn't seem to have access to the component that I've designated for output. When I trigger events through the component, the service handles them and places output in that component. However, when I trigger them through another component, they go to the second instance and do not produce output.

My app has multiple feature modules, which are imported to a core module and then to the app module  (app-->core-->feature). I've tried providing the service in a separate module and importing it to app but this doesn't make any difference. Is there any way to keep the second instance from appearing? Shouldn't 'root' take care of this?

At this point I'm thinking of using the classic OOP strategy of setting a static variable for the service and then having the constructor either set that or return it if it's already defined. However that pattern is definitely not standard Angular.

Comment: Have you added this service somewhere in a `providers` array, that would explain several instances.

Comment: I ran a grep search on all .ts files for providers and didn't find any references, so it looks like I'm all-in on the providedIn: syntax. After some additional tests I get the feeling it's my feature module import strategy that's to blame. I'm trying to get FM-A module to push updates to a component in another FM-B. I've tried importing FM-B into FM-A and also tried importing FM-A& FM-B into app.module but it doesn't seem to change anything. It somehow appears that the second feature module is creating its own instance.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I have the answer and it's a good one. VSCode has a bug which causes it to intermittently add the .js extension to Typescript class imports. This often doesn't impact the functioning of the code since the .js classes do get created at runtime by the TS transpiler (even though we'd all prefer that it point to the original .ts files). However, this causes Angular to recognize the .js files as a different file and if that file includes a service causes it to create a new service instance, as happened here. It's something I'll definitely be on the lookout for in the future.

Comment: Similar problem for me. The `import` statement for my service was sometimes with a .js extension and sometimes without. Had the same effect of causing Angular to see two different files. Also we are using ngUpgrade which might have something to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by a different module declaring its own provider for the service - either by listing it in its `providers`, or by importing a module who does.

You can debug this by setting a break point in the service constructor, and checking the caller's variables to find out which injector creates the second instance (and for which token, in case that's relevant). This should lead you to the module that declares the additional provider.

Comment: I tried renaming the service (filename & class name) and going through each call to update it. This didn't fix it. I'll try a breakpoint.